# How to ban registrations from TOR exits?

Tags: geolocation, spam-prevention

I am getting far too many fake registrations through TOR exits. I would like to block these registrations like major sites do. What is the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Refer http://torproject.org/docs/faq-abuse.html.en#Bans

> First, ask yourself if there's a way to do application-level decisions to separate the legitimate users from the jerks.
>
> Second, consider that hundreds of thousands of people use Tor every day simply for good data hygiene.
>
> Ask yourself what you do about other services that aggregate many users behind a few IP addresses; Tor is not so different from AOL in this respect.
>
> Lastly, please remember that Tor relays have [individual exit policies](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TheOnionRouter/TorFAQ#ExitPolicies).
>
> If you really want to do this, we provide a [Tor exit relay list](https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py) or a [DNS-based list](https://www.torproject.org/projects/tordnsel.html.en) you can query.